# Creating new project with Map.aptx now has World Hillshade basemap?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online-basemaps, template

Prior to updating ArcGIS Pro from version 2.1.3 to 2.2.0, I am near certain that using the Map.aptx template to create a new project did that and inserted a map with one layer named Topographic.

However, now (and presumably as a result of updating to 2.2.0) when I use the Map.aptx template to create a new project it inserts a map with two layers:

- World Topographic Map
- World Hillshade

Can anyone confirm whether this behaviour did change between 2.1.3 and 2.2.0, or whether I have inadvertently altered the contents of my Map.aptx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, same for me when I updated to 2.2:

[image]